# How does Monetdb schedule its MAL instructions and threads?

Tags: database, multithreading, monetdb

Monetdb profiler stethoscope shows that MAL instructions are assigned to different threads.  What's the policy inside monetdb governing this? To which thread, a MAL instruction should be assigned? Is there a maximum number threads to be used?

And, does monetdb manages the CPU affiliation of its threads? To which socket, a monetdb thread will be assigned?

Is there any document available talking about this? I tried but didn't find any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They seem to have several mailing lists, at https://www.monetdb.org/Developers/Mailinglists

I suggest you join the users list and ask them....

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am already trying to do so. But I think maybe stackoverflow can offer me some information on this!

Answer (score 0):

Monetdb has a specific worker thread for each client . It also has (n-1) worker threads where n equals number of cores in the system . These general workers can be used by any clients . For more info look into source code for file mal_dataflow.c.